# Play 1.3 - JPABase InvalidClassException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I'm working with play 1.2.7 since last year, but now I want to update my play apps to 1.3.0 (release this year). I have many apps on different servers that use the same MemCachedServer.

When I update one of my app to play 1.3.0 a lot of Cache Requests is throwing this Exception:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: play.db.jpa.JPABase; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8484463844661198826, local class serialVersionUID = 1652293225498724720
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:617)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
```

I opened the source code of JPABase and it implements Serializable (but dont explicit declare serialVersion), I think that one of my app is setting the object on Cache with the JPABase of Play 1.2.7 and when the others one try to get this object from cache (with JPABase of Play 1.3.0) it throw the exception.

Have anyone experienced this problem? Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you trying to do: **rm -rf tmp** and than run play?

Comment: Yes man, we run play clean too... but for resolve this problem we update all applications to Play 1.3.0 and explicitly declare the serial version... this resolved the problem